# CSS Only - Sticky top navigation after scrolling outside of header

Tags: css, sticky

Is it possible to have the following without the need for javascript? So pure css using the `sticky` position.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}

.sticky-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: pink;
}

.nav-items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-items li {
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.header-content {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.site-content {
  min-height: 2000px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="sticky-nav">
    <ul class="nav-items">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    Part of the Header
  </div>
</header>

<div class="site-content">
  <p>
    When the user scrolls to this point (site-content) - the top nav should now be sticky
  </p>
</div>
```

With a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eyfbh3v2/

Is it possible to have the top `sticky-nav` only be fixed to the top of the page after the header has scrolled out of viewpoint / .site-content hits the top of the page when scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately sticky property is only available within the parent tag where it is define

> This value always creates a new stacking context. Note that a sticky
> element "sticks" to its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling
> mechanism" (created when overflow is hidden, scroll, auto, or
> overlay), even if that ancestor isn't the nearest actually scrolling
> ancestor. This effectively inhibits any "sticky" behavior (see the
> GitHub issue on W3C CSSWG).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

If you don't want to change the structure of your page one way can be to play with the fixed position for the tag `sticky-nav`

```
.sticky-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: pink;
}
```

one other way is to have the sticky tag at the same parent level as the `site-content`